# Xcode "Message from debugger: got unexpected response to k packet: OK"

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, xcode6.4, xcode7.2

I got this message when testing my app on simulator:

> Message from debugger: got unexpected response to k packet: OK

What does it mean and is my app in any sort of danger?

Using Xcode 6.4 & 7.2

Comment: Are we supposed guess what your code is doing? Show the relevant parts responsible.

Comment: Posting code is irrelevant due to the fact that I have no idea what a k packet is and what code it could be referencing with this message. It's not a crash - just this message I've never seen.

Comment: If the code is irrelevant then I'm guessing the message is too...

Comment: same here. this message is displayed even the debug session is not yet started.

Comment: My guess, is Apple silently forces us to use new xCode 7.  Some crashes of xCode during debug have become frequent last  month... Now this message.

Comment: I got another k packet message today. Didn't really look at it. I was trying to save data to a file path, something went wrong and thousands of objects got created. Got a memory warning and then some k packet message. Does anyone know what a k packet is? Is it some atavistic C ghost coming back to haunt contemporary coders?

Comment: I got that error, too. Is anyone else using a real device instead of a Simulator? I've never seen it before until today, and I was using a real device. I unplugged my device (I don't remember if the project was still running, or not). A while later, I found that error in my console.

Comment: same message here.. The funny thing is my xcode-7 is also not calling a function. It is a simple function call. The debugger goes all the way to the function call points but never calls it and k packet error pops in console. It does not crash or anything.. the code moves on without calling the function.

Comment: Got it again just now. Clicked run, and I guess it built on Simulator 5S but then I stopped it. Got the message when I stopped it.

Comment: I am also got the same error while running on the device. Don't know what to do. Any help plz...

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the file [ProcessGDBRemote.cpp](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/source/Plugins/Process/gdb-remote/ProcessGDBRemote.cpp) in the llvm source code, you will see that this occurs when there is an unexpected response from Xcode's debugger process, in this case if the packet is not the `'W'` or `'X'` characters:

```
Error
ProcessGDBRemote::DoDestroy ()
{

    // ...

    if (m_gdb_comm.SendPacketAndWaitForResponse("k", 1, response, send_async) == GDBRemoteCommunication::PacketResult::Success)
    {
        char packet_cmd = response.GetChar(0);

        if (packet_cmd == 'W' || packet_cmd == 'X')
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            if (log)
            log->Printf ("ProcessGDBRemote::DoDestroy - got unexpected response to k packet: %s", response.GetStringRef().c_str());
            exit_string.assign("got unexpected response to k packet: ");
            exit_string.append(response.GetStringRef());
    }

    // ...

    SetExitStatus(exit_status, exit_string.c_str());

    StopAsyncThread ();
    KillDebugserverProcess ();
    return error;
}
```

In this case the debugger is sending the string `"OK"` instead of `"W"` or `"X"`.  There's nothing you can do, there's a problem behind the scenes in Xcode.  I've found that a combination of killing Xcode's debugging processes, restarting Xcode, and restarting your machine before reconnecting to a debugging session can fix this issue.

To learn more about native processes on OS X, checkout the comment inside of that nested `if` statement:

> ```
> // For Native processes on Mac OS X, we launch through the Host Platform, then hand the process off
> // to debugserver, which becomes the parent process through "PT_ATTACH".  Then when we go to kill
> // the process on Mac OS X we call ptrace(PT_KILL) to kill it, then we call waitpid which returns
> // with no error and the correct status.  But amusingly enough that doesn't seem to actually reap
> // the process, but instead it is left around as a Zombie.  Probably the kernel is in the process of
> // switching ownership back to lldb which was the original parent, and gets confused in the handoff.
> // Anyway, so call waitpid here to finally reap it.
> ```

Helpful comments on why this error might occur:

> ```
> // There is a bug in older iOS debugservers where they don't shut down the process
> // they are debugging properly.  If the process is sitting at a breakpoint or an exception,
> // this can cause problems with restarting.  So we check to see if any of our threads are stopped
> // at a breakpoint, and if so we remove all the breakpoints, resume the process, and THEN
> // destroy it again.
> //
> // Note, we don't have a good way to test the version of debugserver, but I happen to know that
> // the set of all the iOS debugservers which don't support GetThreadSuffixSupported() and that of
> // the debugservers with this bug are equal.  There really should be a better way to test this!
> //
> // We also use m_destroy_tried_resuming to make sure we only do this once, if we resume and then halt and
> // get called here to destroy again and we're still at a breakpoint or exception, then we should
> // just do the straight-forward kill.
> //
> // And of course, if we weren't able to stop the process by the time we get here, it isn't
> // necessary (or helpful) to do any of this.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It's Xcode "acting up". I also got it once and fixed it by running this in Terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/* ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/*
```

Basically clears Xcode caches and derived data which sometimes get corrupt. Hope it works for you.

Comment: I'll try this if it happens again. Do you know what a `k packet` is?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs Yes I'm eagering to know what's that too.